What site should I post a question about problems with graphing a specific function in Geogebra?
My question: What site should I post a question about problems with graphing functions in Geogebra?
I have a question about a problem that has arisen while using Geogebra, specifically where I am unable to plot a function f(x,y) which contains both real and imaginary parts. (which Geogebra is able to handle to the best of my knowledge) This question would be about  what I am doing wrong when plotting said function (i.e. What am I doing wrong when plotting  _?)
Right now, I'm thinking that it might either be appropriate to post on SO (because there is a [geogebra] tag I could use) or Math.SE (since I have this question concerning trouble plotting a specific function), although I'm not really sure.

Related on Math.SE Meta

From the comments on the linked Math.SE Meta post:

[4] If it is a math question, ask here. I[f] it is an implementation question, do not ask here. -Xander Henderson [Mod] Apr 9 at 20:44[5] Yes, it [plotting a function] very likely would fall under the general umbrella of "implementation". Which would make it off-topic here. (Which is not to say that it would be on-topic on SO, but such a question is not on-topic here.) -Xander Henderson [Mod] Apr 9 at 21:07


So in general:

This type of question should be asked on Stack Overflow, but that does not necessarily mean that it would be on topic there either. (like if it wasn't phrased as a programming problem)
Also, as @hardmath noted on my post, and as noted on an older Math.SE Meta post (linked by @MartinSleziak), I could also post this as a "how do I plot ___" query on the Geogebra help center.


Overall:

If it is a specific implementation problem that I am having trouble with, then that question should be asked on Stack Overflow.
If it is a specific math problem relating to Geogebra, then Math.SE.
If it is just a simple "how do I plot ___" question, then the Geogebra help center would probably be the best bet.

